# Can't initialise the blank final field

Tags: java, spring, scope, annotations

I found similar questions when looking for an answer, but, none of them respond to my request.

I created a model 'meeting'

```
@Entity
@Scope("prototype")
@Table(name="MEETINGS")
public class Meeting {



@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="name", nullable=false)
private String name;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="description", nullable=false)
private String description;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="allowStartStopRecording", nullable=false)
private String allowStartStopRecording;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="autoStartRecording", nullable=false)
private String autoStartRecording;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="record", nullable=false)
private String record;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name="voiceBridge", nullable=false)
private String voiceBridge;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getAllowStartStopRecording() {
    return allowStartStopRecording;
}

public void setAllowStartStopRecording(String allowStartStopRecording) {
    this.allowStartStopRecording = allowStartStopRecording;
}

public String getAutoStartRecording() {
    return autoStartRecording;
}

public void setAutoStartRecording(String autoStartRecording) {
    this.autoStartRecording = autoStartRecording;
}

public String getRecord() {
    return record;
}

public void setRecord(String record) {
    this.record = record;
}

public String getVoiceBridge() {
    return voiceBridge;
}

public void setVoiceBridge(String voiceBridge) {
    this.voiceBridge = voiceBridge;
}


}
```

and while trying to create a DAO 'MeetingDAO',

```
public interface MeetingDAO {

Meeting meeting;

String createMeeting();

String deleteMeeting();

String getMeetings();

String updateMeeting();
}
```

I got the following error :  The blank final field meeting may not have been initialized   in the line that contains Meeting meetings;

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceDef.html

It is said that:

> All constant values defined in an interface are implicitly public,
>   static, and final. Once again, you can omit these modifiers.

So the variable declaration `Meeting meeting;` in interface `MeetingDAO` turns out to be: `public static final Meeting meeting;` You left it uninitialized. This is the reason you get: `blank final field meeting may not have been initialized` compilation error.

Another thing your interface `MeetingDAO` might look like following (other variations are also possible):

```
import java.util.List;

public interface MeetingDAO {

    void createMeeting(Meeting meeting);

    Meeting getMeeting(long meetingId);

    void deleteMeeting(long meetingId);

    List<Meeting> getMeetings();

    void updateMeeting(Meeting meeting);
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do
and It's working

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to declare a member variable in an interface:

```
public interface MeetingDAO {

    Meeting meeting;
```

You cannot declare member variables in interfaces. The member `meeting` is automatically made `public static final` (i.e., a constant) and you're not initializing it.

Don't declare `meeting` in the `MeetingDAO` interface. If you need to declare a member variable of type `Meeting`, do it in a class that implements the interface. But frankly, it would be strange if an implementation of `MeetingDAO` had a member variable of type `Meeting` - so you probably shouldn't have this member variable at all.

(Also, why are all the methods in the interface returning `String` and not taking any parameters? That doesn't look very logical).

Comment: Yeah, you are right
I made a big mistake, I didn't pay attention to this
well, for the returning types, I was just testing, they will have different types and parameters